# Rename duplicates in an array JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, object, rename

I am asking for help to solve the problem renaming the strings in array that looks like this:

```
["a(1)","a(6)","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a"]
```

After the function execution it should look as follows:

```
["a(1)","a(6)","a","a(2)","a(3)","a(4)","a(5)","a(7)","a(8)","a(9)","a(10)","a(11)"]
```

Empty array and array free of duplicates should left untouched.

My idea is to populate an empty object with key/value pairs and then just push them to a new array:

```
function renameFiles(arr){
    var itemsObj = {};
    var count = 1;
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){

        itemsObj[arr[i]] = count;
        // if the key present, rename the array item and add it to the 
        // itemsObj
        if (arr[i] in itemsObj){
            itemsObj[arr[i] + '(' + (i - (i - 1)) + ')']
        }

    }
    console.log(itemsObj)
    // once the itmesObj is set, run the loop and push the keys to the 
    // array
    return arr;

}

var array = ["a(1)","a(6)","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a"]
renameFiles(array);
```

The problem is that the `itemsObj` is not get populated with duplicates keys. There should be some other method that can handle this task. I am a beginner and probably not aware of that method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there. You'd keep a count, and check for duplicates, and then do another check for duplicates with parentheses, and update the count appropriately

```js
function renameFiles(arr){
  var count = {};
  arr.forEach(function(x,i) {

    if ( arr.indexOf(x) !== i ) {
      var c = x in count ? count[x] = count[x] + 1 : count[x] = 1;
      var j = c + 1;
      var k = x + '(' + j + ')';

      while( arr.indexOf(k) !== -1 ) k = x + '(' + (++j) + ')';
      arr[i] = k;
    }
  });
  return arr;
}

var res = renameFiles(["a(1)","a(6)","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a"]);
console.log(res)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {top:0; max-height:100%!important}
```

Comment: Hmmm. you learn something new every day. didn't know you could increment inside a ternary operator.

Comment: @Skam - You can increment just fine, but relying on the result of assigment, as I'm doing above, should be avoided in many cases, at least in my opinion. I did it here to avoid a whole `if/else` mess checking for keys etc, and I think it's fine as there shouldn't be any issues doing it this way *in this specific case* !

Comment: @adeneo Would you please explain this line `var c = x in count ? count[x] = count[x] + 1 : count[x] = 1;` I am not familiar yet with this kind of style.

Comment: Sure, if `x` is in `count`, then do `count[x] = count[x] + 1` which just adds one to the count, else if `x` is not in `count`, set it to `1`. As assignment always return the assigned value, I'm getting whatever is set back in `c`, i.e. the current count.

Comment: @adeno Thank you sir!! Your are very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You were on the right track.

Another solution,

```
(function(){
    var renameFiles = function(arr){
        var counts = {}
        for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
            if(!counts[arr[i]])
                counts[arr[i]]=0;
            counts[arr[i]]++;
        }
        arr = [];
        for(var name in counts){
            for(var i=0;i<counts[name];i++){
                arr.push(name+(i===0?'':'('+i+')'));
            }
        }
        return arr;
    }

    var array = ["a(1)","a(6)","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a"];
    console.log(renameFiles(array))
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = ["a(1)","a(6)","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a"]

function renameFiles(arr){
  var dup_count, new_name;
  arr.forEach((item, index) => {
    dup_count = arr.filter(x => x == item).length;
    if (dup_count > 1) {
      for(n = 0; n < dup_count;){
        do {
          new_name = `${item}(${n+=1})`;
        } while (arr.includes(new_name));
        arr[arr.indexOf(item)] = new_name;
      }
    }
  });
  return arr
}
> renameFiles(arr)
< (12) ["a(1)", "a(6)", "a(2)", "a(3)", "a(4)", "a(5)", "a(7)", "a(8)", "a(9)", "a(10)", "a(11)", "a"]
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the same result without mutation you can use the following code. Whilst it is much more code a majority of the functions I have included can be replaced with functions included with Ramda or another FP library. I find the following more readable, however that is simple a matter of preference.

Working sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-sun-nrzcc?file=/src/index.js:0-1912).

```js
const incrementingList = (n) => [...Array(n).keys()];
const formatStr = (key) => ifElse(equals(0))(always(key))(concat(key));

const incValues = (obj) =>
  flatMap((key) => map(formatStr(key))(incrementingList(obj[key])))(keys(obj));

const incOrInit = (record, key) =>
  isNil(record[key])
    ? assoc(key)(1)(record)
    : assoc(key)(inc(record[key]))(record);

const generateCounts = reduce({})(incOrInit);
const renameList = compose(incValues, generateCounts);

const list = ["a", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a", "c", "c", "c", "d"];
const result = renameList(list);
console.log(result); // => ["a", "a1", "a2", "b", "b1", "b2", "c", "c1", "c2", "d"]

// THESE FUNCTIONS CAN BE REPLACE WITH RAMDA \\

function keys(obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj);
}

function ifElse(cond) {
  return function ifTrueFn(trueFn) {
    return function ifFalseFn(falseFn) {
      return function passValue(value) {
        return cond(value) ? trueFn(value) : falseFn(value);
      };
    };
  };
}

function always(value) {
  return function alwaysInner() {
    return value;
  };
}

function concat(a) {
  return function inner(b) {
    return a.concat(b);
  };
}

function equals(a) {
  return function equalsInner(b) {
    return a === b;
  };
}

function compose2(fn1, fn2) {
  return function passArg(...args) {
    return fn1(fn2(...args));
  };
}

function compose(...fns) {
  return fns.reduce(compose2);
}

function flatMap(mapFn) {
  return function inner(list) {
    return list.flatMap(mapFn);
  };
}

function map(mapFn) {
  return function passList(list) {
    return list.map(mapFn);
  };
}

function reduce(init) {
  return function reducer(reducer) {
    return function data(data) {
      return data.reduce(reducer, init);
    };
  };
}

function assoc(key) {
  return function assocValue(value) {
    return function assocObject(obj) {
      return { ...obj, [key]: value };
    };
  };
}

function inc(n) {
  return n + 1;
}

function isNil(value) {
  return value == null;
}
```